# How to access global Frame in a pure C# code in UWP project?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have an UWP project and for those pages, they have `.xaml` and `.xaml.cs` file. In the cs file, I can use below code to access `Frame` and do page navigation.

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(AudioPlayer1), data);
```

But also we add some pure cs files(without corresponding .xaml file), and in this pure cs file if I use above method, error occurs like below(`Template.cs` is the file). How to do page navigation in this kind of pure cs file? Or how to access `Frame` in pure cs file?

> 'Template' does not contain a definition for 'Frame' and no accessible extension method 'Frame' accepting a first argument of type 'Template' could be found

Comment: I am guessing your Template.cs file should inherit fro the `Page` or `UserControl` to access 'Frame'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check your project's 'App.xaml.cs' file, you will know how to get or create such a `Frame`.

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

    // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
    // just ensure that the window is active
    if (rootFrame == null)
    {
        // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
        rootFrame = new Frame();

        rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;
     }
     ......
}
```